# Django. When we login how we are automatically moved from AnonymousUser to AbstractBaseUser

Tags: python, django, authentication

I noticed when we login in Django we are no longer AnonymousUser (in models.py) but rather become AbstractBaseUser (in models.py).

How does django handle this change ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'How does django **handle** this change ?'.

Comment: Where is the code that explicitly make the move from AnonymousUser to AbstractBaseUser.

Comment: Its inside django.contrib.auth.models. Check it.

Comment: I said in the question it is in django.contrib.auth.models.py but where is the change between the classes happening ? @Karl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it is inside the `AuthenticationMiddleware` of **django/contrib/auth/middleware.py**: [`request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L22)

which calls the `get_user` from the same module:

[`def get_user(request):
    if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
        request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
    return request._cached_user`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L10)

and finally `get_user` from **django/contrib/auth/__init__.py** which returns [`return user or AnonymousUser()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L181).
Most probably you are interested in the last one.

Comment: so it's basically stored as cookies ?

Comment: What exactly "stored as cookies"? The user object? It could depend on your [`SESSION_ENGINE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_ENGINE) used, but the default one (`django.contrib.sessions.backends.db`) is storing session and all its' attributes server-side and keeps only the [`sessionid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name) in cookies.